# Find and select only element that has a given attribute whose value contains a unique data

Tags: xml, xslt

Following is the XMl file

```
enter code here <items> <item itemcode= "ABC10145" code= "74582 >10</item><item itemcode = "CBD748   Code = "9636">20</item> </items>
```

I want to write a XSLT code that only prints an element that contains an attribute with `value = "ABC10145"` and also it's item `value = "10"`. The rest of data should be eliminated.

Comment: **1.** Please post the **exact** output you expect to get. **2.** Please clarify "*contains an attribute with value = "ABC10145"*" : do you mean **any** attribute with such value, or specifically the `itemcode` attribute?

Comment: 1.Expected result should look like this: <items> <item itemcode = "ABC10145" >10</item>

Answer (score 0):

I have made couple of changes in the input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<items> 
<item itemcode= "ABC10145" code= "74582" >10</item>
<item itemcode = "CBD748"   code = "9636">20</item> 
</items>
```

You can use below template to print only   attribute with value = "ABC10145" and also it's item value = "10"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/items/item[@itemcode!='ABC10145' and .!=10]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response, it has helped me in a way but not giving out what i actually wanted.                                                                     using this code <xsl:template match="@*[not(name()='itemCode')]"> prints out all attribute name : itemcode but i need something that only print ttribute with value = "ABC10145" and also it's item value = "10"

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/items/item[@itemcode!='ABC10145' and .!=10]"/>
<xsl:template match="/items/item/@code"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Use <xsl:template match="/items/item/@code"/> to remove the code attribute

Answer (score 0):

The expected result can achieved quite simply by:

XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="itemcode" select="'ABC10145'"/>
<xsl:param name="value" select="'10'"/>

<xsl:template match="/items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="item[@itemcode=$itemcode and .=$value]">
            <item itemcode="{@itemcode}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am assuming you would want to parametrize the search values.